# Javascript: Sort list based on a value in a child element with a class

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have an unordered list. I am sorting it using the below, which works correctly:

```
sortList(document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0]);

function sortList(ul){
    var new_ul = ul.cloneNode(false);

    // Add all lis to an array
    var lis = [];
    for(var i = ul.childNodes.length; i--;){
        if(ul.childNodes[i].nodeName === 'LI')
            lis.push(ul.childNodes[i]);
    }

    // Sort the lis in descending order
    lis.sort(function(a, b){
       return parseInt(b.childNodes[0].data , 10) - 
              parseInt(a.childNodes[0].data , 10);
    });

    // Add them into the ul in order
    for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)
        new_ul.appendChild(lis[i]);
    ul.parentNode.replaceChild(new_ul, ul);
}
```

This works correctly on a list formatted like this:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>3</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

However, I'm trying to sort the list based on a value contained in a child element with a class, like this:

```
<ul class="list">
<li>
    <div class="stuff etc">
        Stuff
    </div>
    <span class="_5n6h">0</span>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="stuff etc">
        Stuff
    </div>
    <span class="_5n6h">7</span>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="stuff etc">
        Stuff
    </div>
    <span class="_5n6h">4</span>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="stuff etc">
        Stuff
    </div>
    <span class="_5n6h">3</span>
</li>
```

And I want to sort the list items based on the value in the span element with the class _5n6h.

How can I target that value to sort the list items?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You want to sort them asc or desc ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
sortList(document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0]);

function sortList(ul){
   const allItems = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
   const sortedItems = Array.from(allItems).sort((a, b) => {
      a = Number(a.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText);
      b = Number(b.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText);
      return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
   });
   ul.append(sortedItems[0]);
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
      <div class="stuff etc">
          Stuff
      </div>
      <span class="_5n6h">0</span>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div class="stuff etc">
          Stuff
      </div>
      <span class="_5n6h">7</span>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div class="stuff etc">
          Stuff
      </div>
      <span class="_5n6h">4</span>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div class="stuff etc">
          Stuff
      </div>
      <span class="_5n6h">3</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This will do it for sorting the list desc.
You have to use just Array.sort(), by overriding the `a`,`b` params from the sort method you can achieve this.